# Am I correct here with regards to the trig identity that was used?

Tags: trigonometry, physics

I am doing a physics problem where I am presented with the equation

$$\lvert \nu \rvert [\cos(\theta_1) + \cos(\theta_2)]/\lambda = 2 \lvert \nu \rvert [\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2)/2 \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)/2]/\lambda$$

The way this equation is formatted makes it a bit confusing, but I think the trigonometric identity that is used here is

$$\cos(A) + \cos(B) = -2 \cos \left( \dfrac{A + B}{2} \right) \cos \left( \dfrac{A - B}{2} \right)$$

Am I correct here with regards to the trig identity that was used?

Comment: Remove the negative sign, and you're right.

Comment: Some other minor typos: $/2$ confusing relationship to brackets on right. $/ \lambda$ on the left, $\times \lambda$ on the right.

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar I formatted it in precisely that way for a reason – that was how it was presented to me. If you change it to better formatting, as you have done, it ruins part of the point of my question.

Comment: @Henry That $\times \lambda$ was a typo on my part; you're correct that it should be $/\lambda$.

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar The image here https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Trigonometric_Identities.html has the negative symbol

Comment: Kindly check [this](https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/~maryrees/homepagemath191/trigid.pdf) out

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar Ahh, ok, it seems to be a typo in the source that I linked. Thanks for that!

Comment: The negative sign is definitely an error on their end.

Comment: @ThePointer no issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the identity which you have written is wrong. The correct identity is for

$$\cos(A) + \cos(B) = 2\cos\dfrac{A+B}{2} \cos\dfrac{A-B}{2}$$

Comment: The image here https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Trigonometric_Identities.html has the negative symbol

Comment: Well actually in that image they have taken the angle as negative. However I guess you should use the formula given in answer and then replace A and B by negative integers rather than using directly that formula. That might even confuse you. https://kullabs.com/class-10/optional-mathematics/trigonometry/transformation-of-trigonometric-formulae and https://hi-static.z-dn.net/files/d60/22568f8f2d3850747125d98a840443d2.jpg and https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-cosA-cosB-2-cos-A-B-2-cos-A-B-2 these links will help you in better understanding